# How to create custom clickable sequence of characters

Tags: javascript, highlightjs

I would like to customize an existing [**highlightjs**](https://github.com/highlightjs) language definition,
so some character sequences (based on a regex) become clickable.

The usage scenario is code example in a documentation, where some expressions can be links leading to another documentation page.

Reading the documentation, I understand that I should extend existing language definition in order to add a custom [scope](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/css-classes-reference.html), or perhaps [Markups](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/docs/language-guide.rst#markup-generation), but don't know how.

*(Disclaimer: Never played with JavaScript before)*

### Minimalistic example:

#### Code

```cpp
static_assert(csl::ag::size<A>::value == 2);
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ goal : this expression as a link
```

#### Current behavior :

```html
<code class="hljs language-cpp">

<span class="hljs-built_in">static_assert</span>
(csl::ag::size&lt;A&gt;::value == 
<span class="hljs-number">2</span>);

</code>
```

#### Expected behavior:

```html
<code class="hljs language-cpp">

<span class="hljs-built_in">static_assert</span>
(
<span class="hljs-some_custom_name_here">csl::ag::size&lt;A&gt;</span>
::value == 
<span class="hljs-number">2</span>);

</code>
```

Where `<span class="hljs-some_custom_name_here">csl::ag::size&lt;A&gt;</span>` will then become clickable with extra code.